# Basics of how to make HTTP request from ground up which can be use for Oauth and diiferent api calls

Tags: android, http

There Are frameworks like Retrofit but I want to learn basics and there are lots of classes availble and its confusing please mention some references if available.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit uses OkHttp as default.

I personally include `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0` on dependencies

and I use it this way:

```
private Response post(String url, String body) throws IOException {
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), body);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build();
    return <yourOkHttpClient>.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

You have several tutorials on how to make the requests you want if you search for it.

You also have other, more robust frameworks, like Volley that is recently supported b Google, which you can use.